# This Struts2 param tag giving null value when i used request.getParameter("imeino")

Tags: java, struts2

This Struts2 param tag giving null value when i use `request.getParameter("imeino")`

```html
<ws:url id="remoteurl" action='userimageGrid' escapeAmp="false">
    <ws:param name="imeino" value="66666666666"></ws:param>
</ws:url>
```